# Why are the roots of the polynomial $z^N = a^N$ equal to $z_k = a \ e^{j\frac{2 \pi k}{N}}$?

Tags: complex-numbers, arithmetic

I am trying to understand equation 3.28 from this image in my book.

[image]

I get everything that the author is saying, except for when he finds the roots, (zeros), of $z^N = a^N$. Of course, there are going to be $N$ roots. He says the roots are given by $z_k = a \ e^{j \frac{2 \pi k}{N}}$.

What I do not understand is why they HAVE to be evenly spaced around a circle here? Where does it say that they have to be evenly spaced here? Why arent they all squished to one part of the circle, or why cant they be randomly spaced within the circle? I get that yes, those are solutions, but I can think of an infinitely more number of solutions that are all on the circle, but not evenly spaced...

Would appreciate someome elucidating this for me. Thank you.

Comment: Please don't clutter with unnecessary tags. No doubt there are applications to signal-processing, but it's just a question about the arithmetic of complex numbers; let's leave it at that.

Comment: @GerryMyerson May I ask why you are removing the roots and roots of unity tag(s)? They are central to my question.

Comment: Are you aware of what multiplication of complex numbers looks like geometrically? If $z$ and $w$ are complex numbers, then the magnitudes multiply: $|zw|=|z|\cdot|w|$. And the angles add: $\arg(zw)\equiv\arg(z)+\arg(w)\bmod 2\pi$. So $\arg(z^n)=n\arg z$. In particular if $z^n=1$ then $z$ must have an angle that when multiplied by $n$ yields an integer multiple of $2\pi$. In particular we have roots with angles $2\pi\frac{k}{n}$ for $k=0,\cdots,n-1$. Note that if $k\equiv r$ mod $n$ then $2\pi\frac{k}{n}$ and $2\pi\frac{r}{n}$ are **the same angle**, so $k<0$ or $k\ge n$ is redundant!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find the solutions of $z^n=a^n$ you write the equation in polar coordinates. If $z=re^{j\theta}$, then we have
$$r^ne^{jn\theta}=a^ne^{j0}.$$
The magnitudes must be equal so we get $r^n=a^n$, which implies $r=a$. We also have $e^{jn\theta}=e^{i0}(=1).$ This is satisfied only if $n\theta=2\pi k$ for some integer $k$. So the solutions to the equation are $$z=ae^{j\frac{2\pi k}{n}}$$ where $k$ is an integer. Now you can check that you only get $n$ different complex numbers that correspond to $k=0\ldots n-1$, any other value of $k$ will just be a repeated solution.

**Edit:** We are not forcing the solutions to be evenly spread around the circle, we are just trying to find all the possible solutions. A priori we have a solution for each integer $k$. What I claim is that we have a lot of repeated solutions. For example, $k=0$ and $k=n$ give you the same solution
$$ae^{j\frac{2\pi 0}{n}}=a=ae^{j\frac{2\pi n}{n}}.$$
In fact, it is enough to consider $k=1\ldots n$ because any other $k$ would give you a solution which is already represented in ${1,\ldots,n}$. One way you can think about it is that you start with the solution given by $k=1$ and then increasing $k$ by one corresponds to rotating your solution by a $\frac{2\pi}{n}$ angle. Thus, when your reach $k=n+1$ you have completed a full turn in the circle and you start going through the same solutions.

Comment: Let me digest, ...btw you mean $r$ = $a$ right?

Comment: OK, the part that confuses me is when we say 'for some integer $k$'. The thing is that if I pick ANY integer $k$, I will also have a solution. So why is he saying that $k$ is only for $k = 1, 2, ... N$? Why not for $k = 23, 32, 3112, 23231, -232$, etc? Why cant I pick ANY random $k$ integers here, that WONT divide up the circle evenly?

Comment: @Spacey You're asking why we don't redundantly include the same roots multiple (even an infinite) number of times in our list. For example, $$(-1)^2=(-1)^4=(-1)^6=\cdots \\ (-1)^1=(-1)^3=(-1)^5=\cdots$$ but we might say "the square roots of $1$ are $-1$ and $1$" rather than writing down an infinite list. Well, because sometimes we like narrowly-tailored ideas and dislike redundancy.

Comment: @anon I dont understand. I have N roots. They are on the circle. Why are you forcing those roots to be uniformly spread on the circle? Why cant you have N roots in some other part of the circle? This is what I am not getting..

Comment: @Spacey I am not forcing anything. The angles of $n$th roots must be spaced on a polygon with $n$ vertices. These vertices correspond to $2\pi\frac{k}{n}$ for $k=0,\cdots,n-1$. Once you hit $k\ge n$ or go below $k<0$, you are *repeating the same roots* you already have on the polygon.

Comment: @anon Ok - I understand the wrapping around part, and that they would be redundant, yes. I guess the main point is simply that the solutions are 'forcing' particular angles, and in this case, those angles are $2 \pi \frac{k}{N}$... this would then explain why they have to be evenly spaced across the circle. Is this a correct interpretation?

Comment: Thank you Martin - the part that is confusing me is not the wrapping around part, (I understand that this is redundant). What I am confused about is why we had say, $N$=10 roots evenly spread on the circle, and not say, all randomly spaced on the circle. I think the reason here is because we are solving for angles - and those angles split the circle evenly. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Your equation can be rewritten as
$$\left(\dfrac{z}{a}\right)^N =1$$
Treating $\frac{z}{a}$ as an unknown, we know that the solutions to the equation are the $N^{th}$ roots of unity, i.e. $$\dfrac{z}{a} = e^{j\frac{2\pi k}{N}}$$ where $k = 1, \, 2, \, ..., \, N$.

Multiplying both sides by $a$ gives the desired result.

Comment: Sure, but why does $k$ have to be from 0, 1,2, ... N-1? Why cant $k$ equal 34, -98, 123131, ...? That is the crux of my question. By what right are you forcing it to be 0, 1, 2, ... N-1?

Comment: @Spacey If I asked you which numbers squared to $1$, would you say "plus or minus one" or would you say $(-1)^k$ for all integers $k$? It makes more sense to only list each solution once.

Comment: @anon Ok, let me re-phrase. Lets say $N=10$, so I have 10 roots. Why are those 10 roots evenly spread on the circle? Why cant they all be in, say, just the first quadrant of the circle? They would still satisfy the equation, and be roots. So why not?

Comment: @Spacey Why in the world do you think they still satisfy the equation? That's utterly wrong. Do you think I can just decide for $i$ to be a square root of $1$?